# SKYPE for 13.04

Tags: 13.04

how to insall skype in 13.04,
i used this command --- `sudo apt-get install skype`
bt it comes like this

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

output:

```
[sudo] password for sixdee: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can't run more than one installation or update at given moment. You need to wait all other update-root processes to finish. (Update manager, USC downloading or instaling) etc. After all processes are finished run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are running another install at the same time. You can't run parallel apt-get commands at the same time. That's why it says it can't get the lock for dpkg.

Instead of waiting for all other apt-get commands to finish you can also use Ubuntu Software Center. It handles queuing installations for you.

Comment: its not about root permissions.

Comment: Edited. I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu Software Centre will still hang and  wait apt-get command to finish prior to execute the installation